# How to convert firebase firestore geopoint to a latlng in python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have geopoint fields in firestore.
I want to be able to convert the geopoint back to latlng.
From firestore documentation, the **.getLatitude()** and **getLongitude()** should do the trick.
But this doesn't seem to work with Python. I keep getting the error:

> print(geopoint.getLatitude())
>
> AttributeError: 'GeoPoint' object has no attribute 'getLatitude'

How can I get the geopoint values in Python?

```
geopoint = field['location']

print(geopoint.getLatitude()) 
print(geopoint.getLongitude())
```

Comment: documentSnapshot.to_dict() is not working for me. So I referred to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py#L103 But how can I add GeoPoint in this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @spmaddox mentioned, with Python, the get method is not required.
So the following works:

```
print(geopoint.latitude)
print(geopoint.longitude)
```

Answer (score 3):

GeoPoint has longitude and latitude attributes, reference these instead of the methods you’re using.